# access to child element in tailwind reactjs

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Could you tell me the way to do something like this in tailwindcss:
`first[&>.a-child-class]:text-5xl`

I'm trying to style the first element by the way passing classes when it's rendering,I want to change its child's style, but the code above did not work.

I tried to put that classes inside component by default, but I realized, the component need to reusable, so that it is not reasonable.

please help meeeee.

thank you so much, have nice day.

Comment: are you using map.() to create these children?

Answer (score 1):

In tailwind 3.1, arbitrary variants can be stacked with built-in modifiers or with each other, just like the rest of the modifiers in Tailwind. [You can see the document here.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) You are missing `:` after `first`.

Example:

```
<div className="first:[&>.a-child-class]:text-5xl">
 <p className="a-child-class">first</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">second</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">third</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">forth</p>
</div>
```

[Tailwind Play demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/klhe9gKLLU)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
<div className="first [&_p:nth-child(1)]:text-red-500">
 <p className="a-child-class">first</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">second</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">third</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">forth</p>
</div>
```

or , for high level child

```
<div className="first [&>p:nth-child(1)]:text-red-500">
 <p className="a-child-class">first</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">second</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">third</p>
 <p className="a-child-class">forth</p>
</div>
```